# nodejs fs path and readdirSync

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I try to use the function readdirsync in my app. I want to read a special folder that is in the top of my app root.

```
development
--allure 
----allure-result
--myapproot
----myapp.js
```

I want now to read the folder allure-result
For this I use first:
watch path = "../allure/allure-results/"

```
var watchpath = path.join(__alluredir , 'allure-results/');
var dirFiles1 = fs.readdirSync(watchpath);
console.log("Test");
console.log(dirFiles1.length);
```

Then I tried
watch path = "/users/myname/development/allure/allure-results/"

```
var watchpath = path.join(__watchdir , 'allure-results/');
var dirFiles1 = fs.readdirSync(watchpath);
console.log("Test");
console.log(dirFiles1.length);
```

The app will not answer the both console.log lines. Just silence. No error in console.log nothing. It looks like readdirSync do not work well.
I also tried

```
var dirFiles1 = await fs.readdirSync(watchpath);
```

There are many files inside the folder. Maybe this is the problem? Hope anyone can help here why the function gives no result.

Answer (score 0):

This is my folder structure ..

Project Name

|-- app.js

|-- package.json

|-- utils

```
     |`-- test
          |-- 1.js
          |-- 2.js
          |-- 3.js
   `
```

|-- package.json

|-- node_modules

When I wanted to list the files under utils/test/*

```
const fs=require('fs');
console.log(fs.readdirSync('./utils/test').length) >>> 3
```

Let me know, if this one isn't working for you !